# How to set POST encoding with request module on node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using request module on node.js but there is something problem with encoding option. beneath codes are simple post request, but I don't know how to set up **encoding of form field data**. I already set headers to             `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=euc-kr'` But it doesn't works. field data is korean, like "안녕하세요", and I should post it with **euc-kr** encoding. (The site takes euc-kr, not utf8)

The same program on Java application, I coded like this :

`PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "euc-kr"));`

But I don't know how to in nodejs. Can anyone give some solution...?

**Code Sample**

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');

//Lets configure and request
request({
    url: 'http://google.com', //URL to hit
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=euc-kr' },
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        field1: 'data',
        field2: 'data'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got a soultion, and I solved this problem.

If you send a data as a form using request module, the module change your form encoding to utf-8 by force. So even you setted your form encoding to another charset, the module changes your charset to utf8 again. You can see that at request.js on line 1120-1130.

So, You'd better send a data by 'body' option, not 'form' option.

Answer (score 1):

Node doesn't support `EUC-KR` so you can use [`iconv-lite`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) to extend the native encodings available and set the `encoding` option in `request`.

[List of Natively Supported Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)

`iconv.extendNodeEncodings();` only works for node pre v4+. See [here](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Node-v4-compatibility) to get this working for a newer version of node.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var request = require('request');

// This will add to the native encodings available.
iconv.extendNodeEncodings();

request({
  url: 'http://google.com', //URL to hit
  method: 'POST',
  form: {
    field1: 'data',
    field2: 'data'
  },
  encoding: 'EUC-KR'
}, function(error, response, body){
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode, body);
  }
});

iconv.undoExtendNodeEncodings();
```

Comment: I'm on newest version of node, I don't know how can I set post encoding, Should I have to rollback my node version? If I set value `val = iconv.encode("안녕","euc-kr");` But It doesn't work well,

Comment: I rollbacked nodejs version to 0.12 but it still doesn't work. How can I do it...